# What are devices in this picture?

Tags: arduino-uno

I don't know the name of those. Please advise me.

Thanks very much.

[image]

Comment: Post a link to the video you took the screenshot from.

Comment: The things on the right are just [terminal blocks](http://www.dhgate.com/product/100pcs-lot-vse-413-wago-222-413-3-pin-universal/386668290.html#s1-2-1;disc|3677081584).

Comment: Wires? Pins? Connectors? What has this to do with Arduinos?

Comment: The left item looks like some Arduino clone with custom connectors. The right hand item looks like a scale model of a [J Class Freighter](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/J_class).

Comment: oh, thanks all.
@Mark Smith: it's terminal blocks :D

Answer (score 1):

Item all the way to the right are [these Excellway ET25 2/3/5 Pins Spring Terminal Block Electric Cable Wire Connectors](http://www.banggood.com/5Pcs-235-Pins-Reusable-Spring-Lever-Terminal-Block-Electric-Cable-Wire-Connector-p-1103030.html?rmmds=search-left-hotproducts)

Answer (score 0):

It's a [Seeeduino Lotus](http://wiki.seeed.cc/Seeeduino_Lotus/) (or a clone of it).

[image]